# dplyr::filter groups must contain two specific features

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to keep groups of rows where there are two specific entries in those groups. What is the best way to do this with tidy verse?

Reproducible code:

```
library(tidyverse)

long_format <- iris %>% 
  gather(key = "attribute", value = "measurement", -Species) %>%
  mutate(descriptor = 
           case_when(
             str_extract(attribute, pattern = "\\.(.*)") == ".Width" ~ "Width",
             str_extract(attribute, pattern = "\\.(.*)") == ".Length" ~ "Length")) %>%
  mutate(Feature = 
           case_when(
             str_extract(attribute, pattern = "^(.*?)\\.") == "Sepal." ~ "Sepal",
             str_extract(attribute, pattern = "^(.*?)\\.") == "Petal." ~ "Petal"))

filtered <- long_format %>% 
  filter(measurement > 4)

#^THIS IS JUST SETTING UP THE DATA, and can be mostly ignored


filtered %>%
  group_by(Species, Feature, descriptor, attribute) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Notice, after filtering, only versicolor and Virginia contain both Petal and Sepal. I only want to keep species where I have both Petal and Sepal.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Species, Feature, descriptor [6]
  Species    Feature descriptor attribute    count
  <fct>      <chr>   <chr>      <chr>        <int>
1 setosa     Sepal   Length     Sepal.Length    50
2 setosa     Sepal   Width      Sepal.Width      3
3 versicolor Petal   Length     Petal.Length    34
4 versicolor Sepal   Length     Sepal.Length    50
5 virginica  Petal   Length     Petal.Length    50
6 virginica  Sepal   Length     Sepal.Length    50
```

I tried this, but it's not working. Also, it would be nice to work off the actual names (Sepal and Petal) rather than just the number of unique features, but not required:

```
filtered %>%
  group_by(Species, descriptor, attribute) %>%
  mutate(number_of_features = length(unique(Feature))) %>%
  group_by(Species, Feature, descriptor, attribute, number_of_features) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do a `filter` after grouping by 'Species'

```
  ...%>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  filter(all(c("Petal", "Sepal") %in% Feature))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Species [2]
#  Species    Feature descriptor attribute    count
#  <fct>      <chr>   <chr>      <chr>        <int>
#1 versicolor Petal   Length     Petal.Length    34
#2 versicolor Sepal   Length     Sepal.Length    50
#3 virginica  Petal   Length     Petal.Length    50
#4 virginica  Sepal   Length     Sepal.Length    50
```

---

Also, for efficiency purpose, it may be better to `filter` first and then do the `count`

```
filtered %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>%
    filter(all(c("Petal", "Sepal") %in% Feature)) %>%
    count(Species, Feature, descriptor, attribute)
```

When we do data processing/munging, there are certain rules that would be better if followed:

1. `select` only the columns that are needed
2. If a subset of rows are needed, `filter` it first before doing any other computation

Comment: nice and easy. Thank you :)